# What is radial oscillation and how is it measured?

Tags: kinematics, orbital-motion, terminology, oscillators, precession

In the context of the Earth orbiting the sun, the question of the problem is

> "If the radial oscillation has a higher frequency than the time it takes the Earth to orbit the sun, will the aphelion point move in the same direction, not at all ,or the opposite direction as the Earth?"

My question is how do you measure the radial oscillation of the Earth's orbit?

Answer (score 1):

The radial oscillation is just the change of radial distance with time.

For example the Earth's orbit round the Sun is elliptical so the Earth-Sun distance changes during the year. At the farthest distance (aphelion) the Earth Sun distance is about 152 million km while at the closest approach (perihelion) the Earth Sun distance is about 147 million km. So the radial distance oscillates between 152 and 147 million km with a period of a year.